# Get product ID and Vendor ID

Tags: c#, java, usb

Hello guys is there is a way to get the Vendor ID and product is of a USB device using java or C#

Comment: What platform? Probably WMI or JNI on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/)? Granted, it is quite old and not updated, but it seems usb.core API is working for both Linux and Windows.

It's worth taking note I think, how conveniently the [DeviceDesriptor](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/usb/core/DeviceDescriptor.html) class, residing in just the mentioned usb.core package provides getVendorId() and getDeviceId() methods.

Comment: Have you actually _used_ that library?

Comment: Quite a few years back, and only on Linux - can't vouch for Windows. Definitely got proper readings for both vendor and device ID - incidentally that was exaclty what I needed this library for.

Answer (score 1):

USB device are identified by their **vendor id** and **product id**. Those IDs are consisting of a prefix (`vid_` for vendor id or `pid_` for product id) and a 4 digit HEX number. The `MAX3420E` for example has the vendor id `vid_06ba` and the product id `pid_5346`.

for `C#` see these useful articles:

- [Working with USB devices in .NET and C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/)
- [HID USB Driver / Library for .Net / C#](http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/)

Comment: thanks guys it was very helpful i find this library http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/usb/core/DeviceDescriptor.html and i want to use them in an application to get the vendor and product ID .. any ideas  !!!!

Comment: @Mohamed: Salam. i suggested C# way.